# How to have a hybrid static function variable?

Tags: c, static-variables

If I understand correctly, declaring a variable static in a function preserves its value across iterations of that function.  What if I want to preserve a variable's value conditionally?  For example, say I have two functions, `foo()` and `bar()`.  Let's say that every call to `foo()` results in 5 calls to `bar()`.  I have a static variable `x` in `bar()` that is preserved.  What do I do if I want the value of `x` to be preserved across the 5 calls from `foo()`, but then when `foo()` ends the value should be reset?  I'm looking for an explanation as well as example code.

Comment: Then you just use a non-static variable local to `foo()`...

Comment: Is `bar()` invoked anywhere besides from `foo()` ? If not, you don't need a static; you need a *non-static* local variable in `foo()` that is passed by-address to `bar()`.

Comment: What do you mean by `preserved`?

Comment: *"... the value should be reset*": Reset it.